# Why is the stream with a limit infinite?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have run the following code in Eclipse:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "Elsa")
      .filter(n -> n.length() ==4)
      .sorted()
      .limit(2)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

What I was expecting since the limit is two:

```
Elsa
Elsa
```

Can someone please explain why this is an infinite stream?

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) part of the documentation. In particular `sorted` is not a lazy operation, so it needs the whole stream.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing is that [`Stream::generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)) creates an *infinite* stream. That's why the stream is initially infinite.

You limit the stream to two elements by using [`Stream::limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)), which would make it finite.

However, the problem is that you call `sorted()`, which tries to consume the whole stream. You need to limit the stream *before* you sort:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "Elsa")
    .filter(n -> n.length() == 4)
    .limit(2)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The documentation says that [`Stream::sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()) *"is a stateful intermediate operation"*. The Streams documentation about a stateful intermediate operation [explains it very well](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps):

> Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before producing a result. For example, **one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream**.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

There it is. Also note that for all Stream operations, their operation type is mentioned in the Javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain why this is an infinite stream?

Because the [javadoc says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) that is precisely what `Stream.generate()` creates:

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier

Then when you combine that with `sorted()`, you tell it to start a sort on an infinite sequence which will obviously cause the JVM to run out of memory.